# Does Windows reuse data in RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with 10GB of RAM. I have noticed that when I launch some larger application after boot, it takes a while to load. Now when I launch that same application later, it loads much faster. Does Windows keep data in RAM and reuse it when that application is launched again?

Its probably worth noting that I have disabled pagefile in performance settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the DLLs of your application are loaded on-demand at run-time and **they'll stay loaded** unless your system runs out of memory.

So if you start the same program several times, the second run will be faster as a benefit from the **pre-loaded libraries**.

Please [take a look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656914(v=vs.110).aspx):

**Understanding Cold Startup and Warm Startup**

> Cold startup occurs when your application starts for the first time
>   after a system reboot, or when you start your application, close it,
>   and then start it again after a long period of time. When an
>   application starts, if the required pages (code, static data,
>   registry, etc) are not present in the Windows memory manager's standby
>   list, page faults occur. Disk access is required to bring the pages
>   into memory.
>
> Warm startup occurs when most of the pages for the main common
>   language runtime (CLR) components are already loaded in memory, which
>   saves expensive disk access time. That is why a managed application
>   starts faster when it runs a second time.